# Android transparent status bar implementation?

Tags: android, android-theme

I noticed [Play Store application detail pages show a transparent status bar since version 5.4](https://plus.google.com/+KirillGrouchnikov/posts/Jby198p6Jou), but how is it implemented?

I tried to add WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag to my window, but the result is both the status bar and the navigation bar are transparent. How can I just make the status bar transparent but the navigation bar keeps normal?

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 0):

I see your link and see that:
+If you want collapse toolbar like [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout). Try `[CoordinatorLayout][2]`.
+If you just want transparent toolbar try: `android:background="@android:color/transparnt"` on toolbar.
Sorry if I misunderstood your question

Comment: No, what I want is transparent status bar & normal navigation bar. Toolbar is not concerned. Thank you all the same!